# Passing RecordID to Jquery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a button above of my DetailsView. When I click it, it will popup an "Insert Note" dialog (another page in an iframe), this dialog box is using Jquery.  I could'nt figure out how to pass the recordID to this insert page in the dialog popup.

Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AddNewProposal').live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr("href")
            //var page = "ProposalCreateNew.aspx"
            var pagetitle = $(this).attr("title")
            alert(page);
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"  frameBorder="0"  align="middle"> ></iframe>')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 650,
                width: 900,
                title: pagetitle
            });
            $dialog.dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've tried this, but it gives error "Server tags cannot contain <% ... %>"

```
<table width="80%" align="center" >
    <tr>
        <td width="20%"></td>
        <td width="80%" class="PageTitle"></td>
        <td width="20%">
            <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="AddNewProposal" ID="AddNewProposal" Text="Create New" href="ProposalCreateNote.aspx" title="Create Note" class="button3"/>              
        </td>
    </tr>
</table
--- Below is my DetailsView which has a label to display the ProposalID, so I want to grab this ID and pass it to the dialog box (URL + ID) when I click the AddNewProposal button.
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProposedID" SortExpression="Name" > 
     <ItemTemplate >
          <asp:Label ID="ProposalID" runat="Server" 
          style="text-align:left;" Text='<%# Eval("ProposedID")%>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Label` server control is generating a `span` element on client side, so you should be able to get its text like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#<%= AddNewProposal.ClientID %>').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/ProposalCreateNew.aspx")%>' + '?ProposalID=' + encodeURIComponent($('span[id$="ProposalID"]').text());
        var pagetitle = $(this).attr("title");
        alert(page);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"  frameBorder="0"  align="middle"> ></iframe>')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            height: 650,
            width: 900,
            title: pagetitle
        });
        $dialog.dialog('open');
    });
});
</script>
```

Please notice the usage of:

- `ClientID` - to ensure that you are targeting proper elements, the ASP.NET WebForms id can be different on client side (unless you are using [ClientIDMode.Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) in ASP.NET 4.0)
- `ResolveClientUrl` - to ensure the proper URL on the client side (unless you are sure what the URL will be)

You should also be aware that `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 and you should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I tried your suggestion, but keep getting an error "Them Name 'ProposalID' is not in current context".  Perhaps, this Label is inside the DetailsView, which we can not detect the Text value?  Please advise.

Comment: @Milacay I see you have updated your .ASPX code - I have change the selector for span element to more general based on this, please test now (I'm a little bit guessing here as there can be some other things on the page which can complicate things a little bit).

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you so much! Quick question. IF I want to hide the ID in the <FooterTemplate><asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenProposalID" Value='<%# Eval("ProposedID")%>'/> </FooterTemplate>. Can you use the same method to capture the ProposalID?

Comment: @Milacay With HiddenField it is advised to use `.val()` instead of `.text()`.